# Autowired field is throwing NullPointerException on a unit-test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am new, working with Spring Boot. I am writing a unit test and I always got the following exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "com.trivadis.stocks.service.InitializeService.createInitialStocks()"
> because "this.initializeService" is null

I have no idea what I can do. I think that the @AutoWired doesn't work.

The source code of my test:

```
import com.trivadis.stocks.entity.Stock;
import com.trivadis.stocks.repository.StockRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class StockServiceTest {
    private Stock stock1;
    private Stock stock2;
    @Autowired
    StockService stockService;

    @Autowired
    InitializeService initializeService;
    @Autowired
    StockRepository stockRepository;



    /**
     * initializes the needed stock objects and the stockService before any test will be run
     */
    @BeforeEach()
    public void init() {
        initializeService.createInitialStocks();
        stock1 = stockService.getById(1L);
        //stock2 = new Stock("stock1", 2999.98);

    }

    /**
     * Is a test, which will be executed 500 times
     * it tests if the interval of the created random number is correct.
     */
    @RepeatedTest(1)
    void changePrice() {
        stockService.changePrice(stock1.getId(), 1, true);
        System.out.println(stock1.getPrice());
       // assertTrue(stock1.getPrice() >= 1.025);
        //System.out.println(stock1.getPrice());
        //assertTrue(stock1.getPrice() <= 1.15);
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Great, you are writing tests!

Unfortunately, `Autowired` does not work like that, you will need the spring-context which you don't really need if you writing simple unit-tests.

Regarding your unit-test, you are testing `StockServiceTest` so you should focus only on that class `StockService` and mock the behaviour of `InitializeService` and `StockRepository`. I would recommend a quick read of this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unit-testing-best-practices).

For mocking, you can use [Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)

If you want to test both classes, you can initialize them inside the `init()` method but you will have to handle the dependencies they might have.